# BASH: Find lines which is not available on File 2 v File 1

Tags: bash

I am currently writing a bash script to find names that are available in File1 but not available in File2.

File1:
"Name"
"Jeff"
"Michael"
"Ringo"
"John"

File2:
"Name"
"Jeff"
"Michael"
"John"
"Bert"

From the example above, it should return "Ringo". So far, I am running a for loop to extract it.

```
for q in `cat File1 | tail -n +2 | sort`;do grep $q File2 >> output.txt;done
```

However, it would take forever to run it on ~150,000 records. So, is there a better solution you can share for this?

Thanks in advance for the answers.

Comment: you should probably use `-F` option to grep if you are looking for strings and not trying to match regex

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[comm](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/comm.html) is a standard utility for this.

```
tail -n +2 File1 | sort -u > tmp1
sort -u File2 > tmp2

comm -23 tmp1 tmp2 > output.txt
rm tmp1 tmp2
```

With bash, the temporary file cleanup can be avoided:

```
comm -23 \
    <(tail -n +2 File1 | sort -u) \
    <(sort -u File2) \
    > output.txt
```

Note that `sort` works fine on files that do not fit in memory (implementations generally use [mergesort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort) with temporary files if memory usage would become too high). `comm` itself requires minimal memory. I believe overall runtime is O(n*log(n))

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for `diff(1)`. If you have the GNU version, this flag with some output processing to get just the first column.

```
   --suppress-common-lines
      do not output common lines
   --side-by-side, -y
      output in two columns
```

But diff requires lines to be in the same order in both files. If that's not your case, `grep` with multiple expressions and the invert flag `-v`/`--invert-match` and `-E`/`--extended-regexp` might work better.

Also note that I am using command substitution instead of a for loop to run it in one go. The `(x|y)` extended regexp searches `x` OR `y`.

```
grep --invert-match --extended-regexp \
    "^( $(uniq file2 | tr '\n' '|') )$" \
    file1
```

Comment: ahhh. that's what i was thinking. couldn't verify because i am on my phone rn. thanks for pointing out

Comment: Note that if File1 contains `abc` and File2 contains `xxxabcxxx`, you'll get a match. Also the question is using regex when probably whole line fixed string matches are desired (`grep -xF`), so you'd want something to escape metacharacters before running `tr`